# Whenever i try to open a fragment in Kitkat my App crashes the app works fine in Lollipop and higher

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
E/UncaughtException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class TextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
   at in.saneswap.fragment.SwipeWithBuddiesFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:93)
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:2354)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1419)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1740)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1809)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:799)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2580)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2367)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:2322)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:2229)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:700)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/line.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0801d7
   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:806)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(SourceFile:75)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(SourceFile:71)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(SourceFile:103)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(SourceFile:1024)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(SourceFile:1081)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:172)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
   at in.saneswap.fragment.SwipeWithBuddiesFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:93) 
   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:2354) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1419) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1740) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1809) 
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:799) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2580) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2367) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(SourceFile:2322) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(SourceFile:2229) 
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(SourceFile:700) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #0: invalid drawable tag vector
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
```

Comment: Please add relevant code

Comment: check if you have line.xml in res/drawable not drawable-v21

Comment: Please attach the code for line.xml

Comment: Hi Ashish the line.xml code is here.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="5dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/black"
        android:pathData="M0,20h24v4H0z" />
</vector>

Comment: Hello Guys, well I am using this line.xml vector drawable as a background on one of my TextViews. So can please someone tell me how to do it on pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Guys I found that i am using this line.xml vector drawable as a background image for my textview.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html):

> Android 4.4 (API level 20) and lower doesn't support vector drawables. If your minimum API level is set at one of these API levels, you have two options when using Vector Asset Studio: generate Portable Network Graphic (PNG) files (the default) or use the Support Library.

You need to check if you are using some functionality that cannot be backported, otherwise use the support library.